# Using Artifactory as Terraform Registry for custom provider

Tags: artifactory

I run Artifactory 7.49.3 with host artifactory.example.com and I use it to publish custom Terraform Provider. I created a TF repo with provider layout in accordance with [documentation](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/terraform-registry) and uploaded zips. Now I try to use it in TF

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    confu = {
      source = "artifactory.example.com/test/testprovider"
    }
  }
}
```

and terraform init returns

```
The host "artifactory.example.com" given in in provider source address "artifactory.example.com/test/testprovider" does not offer a Terraform provider registry.
```

TF [requires](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/internals/remote-service-discovery#supported-services) service discovery to return provider endpoint, but https://artifactory.example.com/.well-known/terraform.json returns only:

```
{
  "modules.v1" : "https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/terraform/v1/modules/",
  "state.v2" : "https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/terraform/remote/v2",
  "tfe.v2" : "https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/terraform/remote/v2",
  "tfe.v2.1" : "https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/terraform/remote/v2",
  "tfe.v2.2" : "https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/terraform/remote/v2",
  "login.v1" : {
    "client" : "terraform-cli",
    "authz" : "https://artifactory.example.com/ui/terraform/oauth2/authorize",
    "token" : "https://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/api/oauth2/token",
    "grant_types" : [ "authz_code" ]
  }
}
```

and provider endpoint is missing. Is it fixed in some versions? Or it can be configured somehow?

Edit: I know how to make it work via .terraformrc configuration, my question is there a version that implements service discovery for provider registry, so you can just use host without any additional configuration

Comment: Same issue, please let us know if/when you find a solution, I'm trying too, thanks

Comment: @carlitos081 no, just implemented it with corresponding network_mirror in terrafomrc. I assume I can solve it with proxy, which will return proper json on https://artifactory.example.com/.well-known/terraform.json  request, but don't have time for it

Answer (score 1):

I had your same issue and I really struggled to find a solution looking at the jfrog documentation [here](https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/terraform-registry) which is really really poor.
This are the steps I did to resolve the issue:

1. Create a local repository of type terraform module `terraform-module-local`
2. Create a local repository of type terraform provider `terraform-provider-local`
3. Create a remote repository `terraform-remote` with the following configuration:[image]
4. Create a virtual repository `terraform-virtual` and add the 3 repository you created above
5. Go to `terraform-virtual` and click set me up:[image] When create the file `.terraformrc` please follow the official documentation [here](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/config/config-file) which is different for windows or mac/linux
6. Create the zip file from the binary go and push it to the `terraform-provider-local`

After that you will be good to go with just declaring the provider without the host:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    confu = {
      source = "test/testprovider"
    }
  }
}
```

Hope that solve your issue

Comment: Came here to add that the network mirror url needs to end in a '/'. It won't work otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I see that your source is “artifactory.example.com/test/testprovider”. However, the “source” only requires  “namespace/provide-name”.
See the "Set Me Up" Tool in the Artifactory UI, on the top right corner under Application->Artifcatory->Artifacts, as in the screenshot below.

Please update your .tf file accordingly.

[image]

Comment: That's for cases when you have your artifactory configured as default in .terraformrc, no? Otherwise how TF know the host? According to TF doc, source can  have 3 parts https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/requirements#source-addresses